# My Python-3 Code is kinda confuzing if anyone can help i would like to know, I made a window

Tags: python, python-3.x, button

```
#imports
from tkinter import *
import os
```

```
#Window Creation
window = Tk()
window.title('Potato Defense')
window.configure(width=1500, height=1500)
window.configure(bg='lightblue')
photo = PhotoImage(file = r"TestButton.png")
Button(window, text = 'Click Me !', image = photo).pack(side = TOP)

window.mainloop()
```

my code is quite janky, but currently, my image location gives an error because I don't know how to get the current location of files I don't want my directory I want it to work on other pcs. how do I get a current directory?

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: You have to KNOW where the files will be.  Are you bundling this into an executable?  Are you including the images when you build the exe?  And note that "current directory" is almost never what you want in this case.  You don't know what the "current directory" is when others run the app.  You usually want the directory where the Python script is located, because the exe builders put the data files there.  You can get that from `os.dirname(__file__)`.

Comment: no, I will prob be posting it to GitHub as a .zip, but I'm unsure as of now

Comment: do i set `os.dirname(__file__)` as a variable?

Comment: this also does not work as a variable as I do not need the file that the .py is I need the directory of the .py, not the .py itself

Comment: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'dirname'

Comment: Sorry, `os.path.dirname`.

Answer (score -2):

If your code is in the same directory as this file, you can simply do `photo = PhotoImage(file = "./TestButton.png")`

Comment: when I do this I get this error `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "./TestButton.png": no such file or directory`

Comment: Then that means the file is NOT in the "current directory" when you run.

Comment: Please provide more context about where the picture is in relation to your python script then.

Comment: This  answer isn't correct. Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, and that may or may not be the same folder as the file.

Comment: but it is in the same directory

Comment: Starting Potato Defense
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/btp/.coding/Potato Defense FIles/Potato_defense.py", line 13, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file = r"./TestButton.png")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4064, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4009, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "./TestButton.png": no such file or directory